# C++: gcc 4.2.1 gives program which segfaults, not on linux

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The following simple program segfaults on my mac (Lion) running gcc 4.2.1:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct A{
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
    os << 3 << endl;
  }
};

template <typename T>
T f() { return T();}

int f() { return 2;}


int main() {
  cout << f() << endl;

  A a= f<A>();
  cout << a << endl;
}
```

When I run the program, I get:

```
 ./a.out
2
3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

When I do a stacktrace, I get:

```
(gdb) run

Starting program: a.out 
unable to read unknown load command 0x24
unable to read unknown load command 0x26
2
3

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff8b84fa49 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8b84fa49 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fff665c1ae8 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

The backtrace has no useful information (anyone know why?). This works
fine in linux.

Comment: Your `operator<<` is declared to return an `std::ostream&`, but you have no `return` statement.

Comment: I don't have your environment to test with, but my best guess is the absence of `return 0;` from the end of your main. ETA I think @ildjarn's comment is a better guess than mine.

Comment: have you compiled with `-g` ?

Comment: @01d55 : Returning a value from `main` is optional (see §3.6.1/5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's make it clearer what happens

```
(cout << a) << endl;
```

You forgot a `return` in your `operator<<`.

Comment: in particular you should return the reference to the ostream

Comment: I understand my mistake. The compiler should have prevented me from compiling, rather than the program causing a seg fault at runtime.